# Implementing In-app Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am currently working on in app purchase in my application, when it launches I have always the error code -1003 querying owned items response signature verification failed when I arrive in IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener method.

I currently uses the example version of Google "Trivial Drive", I guess my signature is correct because I get to buy much when I use android.app.purchassed ...

The key seems correct to me because when I click like to buy a product that tells me that the publisher can not buy the product which is normal in itself (If I put anything I have another error saying the product does not exist). For cons, I have the same error when I put the test product "android.test.purchasse" then I should be able to test with it.

I made a purchase with android.test.purchasse there and I can not reset if you have already succeeded I'm interested.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // load game data
    loadData();

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MY_KEY_BASE64";

    PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey);
    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}


// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        /*
         * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
         * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
         * verifyDeveloperPayload().
         */
        if(inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_GAS))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PREMIUM",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NOT PREMIUM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));

        // Do we have the infinite gas plan?
        Purchase infiniteGasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_INFINITE_GAS);
        mSubscribedToInfiniteGas = (infiniteGasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(infiniteGasPurchase));
        Log.d(TAG, "User " + (mSubscribedToInfiniteGas ? "HAS" : "DOES NOT HAVE")
                    + " infinite gas subscription.");
        if (mSubscribedToInfiniteGas) mTank = TANK_MAX;

        // Check for gas delivery -- if we own gas, we should fill up the tank immediately
        Purchase gasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS);
        if (gasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(gasPurchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "We have gas. Consuming it.");
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            return;
        }

        updateUi();
        setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

Have you ever been concerned? I see no way out for this bug help from you will be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: you got the solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a test account, and put it in the playstore admin page.